# Single drop-down with search box embedded in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdownbox, search-box

I want to add search box to a single select drop down option.

**Code:**

```
<select id="widget_for" name="{{widget_for}}">
<option value="">select</option>

{% for key, value in dr.items %}

<input placeholder="This ">

<option value="{% firstof value.id key %}" {% if key in selected_value %}selected{% endif %}>{% firstof value.name value %}</option>


{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Is there ant way to do it without using any plugin or datalist-html5 ?